# java Float.MAX_VALUE to Double

Tags: java, floating-point, double

It is this code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      float a = Float.MAX_VALUE;
      double b = (double) a;
      b++;
      System.out.println(b == a);
}
```

and it prints `true`.
Could anyone explain why?

Comment: Floating point values are approximations. With very large numbers it is possible that the closest representable value to `x+1` is `x`, so trying to increment the number by 1 does not affect the value.

Comment: See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The precision of `double` is not capable of representing the difference between `Float.MAX_VALUE` and `Float.MAX_VALUE+1`, so a rounded result is returned. That rounded result is `Float.MAX_VALUE`.

`Float.MAX_VALUE` is 2<sup>128</sup>−2<sup>104</sup>. (Note that this is 2<sup>127</sup>+2<sup>126</sup>+2<sup>125</sup>+…+2<sup>104</sup>. That is, it is the sum of all powers of two from 2<sup>127</sup> to 2<sup>104</sup>. In binary, it has 24 one bits, which is the number of bits in the significand<sup>1</sup> of a `float`. Mathematically, it equals 2<sup>128</sup>−2<sup>104</sup>.)

When you add one to this, the mathematical result is of course 2<sup>128</sup>−2<sup>104</sup>+1. This is not representable in `double`, because the significand of a `double` is 53 bits, but from 2<sup>127</sup> to 1 is 129 bits. You cannot fit bits for both 2<sup>127</sup> and 1 inside the significand of a `double`. When a result is not representable, the nearest representable number is returned.

The representable number just below the mathematical result is 2<sup>128</sup>−2<sup>104</sup>, and the representable number just above the mathematical result is 2<sup>128</sup>−2<sup>104</sup>+2<sup>75</sup>. (Note that from 2<sup>127</sup> to 2<sup>75</sup> is 52 bits, so 2<sup>75</sup> is the smallest power of 2 that bits in a 53-bit significand where the largest bit is being scaled to 2<sup>127</sup>. Thus, we calculated this next number above 2<sup>128</sup>−2<sup>104</sup> by adding the smallest amount to it that fits in the significand.) So we have two candidates:

- 2<sup>128</sup>−2<sup>104</sup>, which is 1 away from 2<sup>128</sup>−2<sup>104</sup>+1.
- 2<sup>128</sup>−2<sup>104</sup>+2<sup>75</sup>, which is 2<sup>104</sup>+2<sup>75</sup>−1 away from 2<sup>128</sup>−2<sup>104</sup>+1.

The former is closer, so it is chosen to be the computed result. Thus, in `double`, adding one to 2<sup>128</sup>−2<sup>104</sup> produces 2<sup>128</sup>−2<sup>104</sup>.

## Footnote

<sup>1</sup> The representation of a binary floating-pont number has three parts:  a sign *s* that is +1 or −1, a significand *f* that is a fixed-point number with a fixed number of bits, and an exponent *e*, such that the number represented is *s* • *f* • 2<sup>*e*</sup>. The significand can be thought of just as an integer with a certain number of bits, but it is often scaled by adjusting the exponent so that the significand of normal floating-point numbers is in [1, 2). For example, 132 could be thought of as the significand 100001<sub>2</sub> times 2<sup>2</sup> or as 1.00001<sub>2</sub> times 2<sup>7</sup>.